# Facebook SDK PHP - a duplicate transaction - issue on IE 9

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-9

I have an weird issue on my application.
When I open the application on IE 9 browser, it shows the following text on alert pop up:

'To display the webpage again, the web browser needs to
resend the information you've previously submitted.

If you were making a purchase, you should click Cancel to
avoid a duplicate transaction. Otherwise, click Retry to display
the webpage again.'

In other browsers there are not any similar issue. I use in PHP SDK and JS connect script.

I've tried to understand what is the reason for it and found that it's caused by facebook all.js script.

Could you please advise?

Thx,
Nimi

Comment: Are you using server-side authentication on load of the application?

Comment: Yes, but it's a regular FB oauth request.